# ffmpeg with libsoxr resolve dependecies

Tags: linux, compilation, ffmpeg, dependencies

I'm trying to compile `ffmpeg` with `libsoxr`, so I use the flag `--enable-libsoxr` when calling `./configure`. I have installed `libsoxr`, and the location of the headers added to `PATH`. However when I try to compile it I get an error: `ERROR: libsoxr not found`, and in `config.log` it says:

```
fatal error: soxr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <soxr.h>
```

I think `./configure` doesn't make use of `PATH` or something...Is there another way to specify dependencies for `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to add the lib path with :

```
./configure ... --sysinclude=/path/to/sox
```

Another solution is to find where ./configure search this lib.

To determine that, a solution is using `strace` like that :

```
strace -f -s 1000 -e trace=file ./configure --enable-libsoxr 2>&1 | grep sox
```

then you can symlink your lib in a searched path.

Comment: @Jelly: Added strace solution.